# Angular Material 5 - How to Customise date in mat-datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

How do I customise mat-datepicker date in MM/DD/YYYY format?

I'm using following following configuration:

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Basic datepicker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-overview-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {}
```

When I print the form value it gives me following output:

> Sun Dec 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

I'm expecting format in MM/DD/YYYY.

I tried this configuration: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats

But it didn't work for me. I'm using default MatNativeDateModule (Not moment js)

Comment: MatNativeDateModule store the date as a Date object. A Date object doesn't have any format. It's an object, wrapping a number of millis since 1970. But you can format it the way you want to, using the date pipe, for example.

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48396025/how-to-customize-date-in-mat-datepicker-to-2017-11-20t112300-angular-mater/48804115#48804115

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the Date Pipe as follows,

```
<input mdInput placeholder="Title" [ngModel]="mydate  | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'">
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-ml9xxw?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks. When I add [ngMode]="mydate  | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'" it says. Property 'mydate' does not exist on type 'FormDateComponent' any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: i have used variable mydate here, you need to replace with your model variable. mark if the answer helped

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured it out. It is working perfectly :)

Comment: `ngModel` is deprecated and we are being forced to use `formControlName` instead in Angular 6+. this question needs a new answer or this answer needs an update.

Comment: as an accessory bit of information. formControlName only exists as a static parameter, you can't `[formControlName]="myDate | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'" `, you are forced to do `[formControlName]="myDate` where myDate is one of the constructed members of a reactive forms, so that means that you have to  perform the pipe on the typescript-side and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 9):

The below code will format the date of all date pickers in your angular application.

Create a constant for date format.

```
export const DateFormat = {
 parse: {
 dateInput: 'input',
 },
display: {
dateInput: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
dateA11yLabel: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
}
};
```

And Use the below code inside app module

```
providers: [
  { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
  { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DateFormat }
 ]
```